# Power shell script works fine in Windows power shell ISE, but it fails when called from ARM template as custom script

Tags: azure, powershell, shell, scripting, arm

my Power shell script works fine in Windows power shell ISE on a new VM to execute few options on my desktop application windows, but same power shell script fails when called from ARM template as custom script. is there any limitation to execute desktop application window screen steps with key strokes operations via powers shell script especially when we try to execute from Custom script of ARM template?

## power shell script - psscript1.ps1:

Write-Host "Open Application Console window"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

& "C:\Program Files\mydesktopapplication\myapp.exe"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 90

Write-Host "open my desktop app window and update"

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

$wshell.SendKeys(“%c {Down} ”)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")

Write-Host "Opened my desktop app window"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 12

$wshell.SendKeys(“%t”)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

## Below is the error I was able to see in Windows event logs:

```
<Data>Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'FileSystem' provider failed.</Data>
<Data>  ProviderName=FileSystem
ExceptionClass=ProviderInvocationException
ErrorCategory=InvalidOperation
ErrorId=InitializeDefaultDrivesException
ErrorMessage=Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'FileSystem' provider failed.

Severity=Warning

SequenceNumber=9

HostName=ConsoleHost
HostVersion=5.1.17763.2183
HostId=2618e0d8-7b84-47af-bf39-185c31fe7663
HostApplication=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; &amp; 'C:\myapp\psscript1.ps1'
```

=========
In my ARM template after creating new VM under resources{} I added below statements with in resources section.

"resources": [

```
    {

      "type": "extensions",

      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",

      "name": "Installation-App",

      "location": "[parameters('location')]",

      "dependsOn": [

        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"

      ],

      "tags": {

        "displayName": "Installation-App"

      },

      "properties": {

        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",

        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",

        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.10",

        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,

        "settings": {

          "timestamp": 123456789

        },

        "protectedSettings": {

          "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ', './', last(split(parameters('scriptURL'), '/')))]",

          "storageAccountName": "<storageacname>",

          "storageAccountKey": "<storageackey>",

          "fileUris": [

            "[parameters('scriptURL')]"

          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Could you please add the PowerShell script that you used and what is the error message you are receiving.

Comment: I have added sample script for your ref. It can be any desktop application windows

Comment: Could you please try to help us with the complete ARM template and from where you are trying to call this PowerShell script inside it and also help us with the complete stack error message

Comment: I don't see any ARM template here could you please help me with it so that we can check in our environment